# Когерентность кэша и Java Memory Model

Tags: многопоточность, java

Может ли [когерентность кэша](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B0) повлиять на работу многопоточного Java-приложения? Или все проблемы решает виртуальная машина?

В каких случаях один и тот же многопоточный код будет работать по-разному в зависимости от кэш-памяти?

Comment: Не очень новые, но, возможно, интересные для вас статьи из серии "Теория и практика Java" от IBM:

 1. [Исправление модели памяти Java][1]
 2. [Построение лучшей HashMap][2]
 3. [Методы безопасного конструирования][3]

Как раз затрагивают тему кэш-когерентности.

  [1]: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp02244/
  [2]: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp08223/
  [3]: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp0618/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По идее для объектов, отмеченных volatile когерентность должна обеспечиваться независимо от аппаратной поддержки когерентности кэшей.

У большинства современных (SMP) компьютеров обеспечение когерентности кэша встроено в конструкцию. Этого нет (насколько мне известно) у HPC (high performance computing) кластеров. Знаю, что в реализации JVM для них обещают Truly portable threads and synchronization model.

Вообще же, проблемы с параллельными потоками **всегда** на совести программиста.

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае, `JVM` и проблема `cache coherence` - это 2 совершенно разных уровня взаимодействия с железом компьютера. Проблема `cache coherence` всегда решается на уровне процессора, в 99% случаев это происходит аппаратно *(в архитектуре `Intel`, насколько мне известно, для этого используются протоколоы [**MESIF**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESIF_protocol) и [**MOESI.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOESI_protocol))*.

---

Единственное, на что реально может влиять `cache coherence` - это на производительность приложения *(например, как влияют промахи кэша)*.

**Теория** подсказывает, что **ситуация, которой стоит избегать** - это помещение нескольких переменных в строку кэша и постоянные чтения-записи между ними. Очевидно, что это плохо, т.к накладные затраты на синхронизацию кэшей будут немаленькими *(разумеется, в случае, если это как-либо не соптимизится).*

**Практика** же подсказывает, что в `Java` выиграть на этом вряд ли удастся.

Три уровня  `JVM` (код - байт-код - оптимизирующий в native код runtime) слабо подразумевают оптимизации такого рода. *Если бы речь шла о `C++`, то еще можно было бы что-нибудь придумать, а здесь, предполагаю, что это практически невозможно, если, разумеется, не использовать `JNI`.*

Comment: "Единственное, на что реально может влиять cache coherence - это на производительность приложения" - абсолютно не согласен. Когерентность кэша влияет на **семантику** доступа к значениям переменных в памяти.

Если один поток изменил переменную, то в **случае когерентного кэша** и volatile (отключает оптимизацию доступа к переменной, например помещение ее промежуточных значений в регистр) поток **уверен**, что это изменение доступно всем другим потокам.

Comment: @avp Если на секунду отвечься от `volatile` и, вообще, синтаксического сахара языков, то я, например, представляю себе все так - у любого многоядерного десктопного процессора *(это просто пример, разумеется)* на каждое ядро приходится своя кэш-память. *Пусть у нас есть фрагмент программы, который выполняется на нескольких ядрах, и получилось так, что какие-то данные угодили в строчку кэша сразу двух ядер, то **некоторые операции чтения-записи должны быть синхронизированы в двух кэшах.*** Как я полагаю, в 99% современных неоднопроцессорных систем, эта проблема решена аппаратно и давным давно.

Comment: @avp Далее, возникает вопрос - как с этим бороться с практической точки зрения в `Java`. Я предполагаю, что никак, т.к вещи вроде [1][**таких**] в `Jav'e` без `JNI` невозможны.

[1]: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads/

Comment: @avp Если я где-то ошибся в толковании понятия, в терминах, или в сути процесса, то **поправьте меня, пожалуйста**, т.к все это достаточно интересно.

Comment: Вы говорите о современных десктопах и здесь все рассуждения правильные т.к. проблемы кэш-когерентности **для них не существует**. Она решена.

Речь идет о кластерах, состоящих из SMP узлов. В каждом узле кэши когерентны, но в целом по всей системе нет. В таких системах возникнет проблема запуска потоков, имеющих общие переменные (в том числе для синхронизации) на разных узлах кластера.

Comment: @avp Звучит разумно. К сожалению, не могу поддержать разговор о кластерах и проблеме когеретности кэшей в ней, т.к сказывается нехватка знаний в этой области. *Поизучаю вопрос на досуге, спасибо.*